# Limitar um EditText de 1 a 100 e incluir o símbolo "%"

Tags: java, android, mask

Estou fazendo um aplicação que pega os dados inseridos em um `EditText` e faz um certo cálculo.

O problema é que eu preciso que o campo vá de 1 a 100%, mas a "mask" que eu estou usando é simples demais pra isso, então ele só faz a limitação mas vai de 0 a 999 e não é isso que eu quero.

Também não consigo colocar o símbolo de % no final desse campo.

Segue o código:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.github.rtoshiro.util.format.MaskFormatter;
import com.github.rtoshiro.util.format.SimpleMaskFormatter;
import com.github.rtoshiro.util.format.pattern.MaskPattern;
import com.github.rtoshiro.util.format.text.MaskTextWatcher;

public class ActivityForm extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText percentual;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_form);

    percentual = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentual_Id);
    SimpleMaskFormatter simpleMaskPercentual = new SimpleMaskFormatter( " NNN% " );
    MaskTextWatcher maskPercentual = new MaskTextWatcher(percentual, simpleMaskPercentual);
    percentual.addTextChangedListener( maskPercentual );
    }
}
```

Comment: Você quer que vá de 1% a 100% ou de 0% a 100%?

Comment: de 1% a 100% porque o cliente deve especificar o quanto ele quer investir

Comment: Ok, editei a minha resposta. Me diga se ela serve.

Comment: Eu sou novo nessa parte de mascaras e to um pouco confuso aqui... eu baixei a dependencia direto do GitHub então só copiei e colei no build.gradle... esse código que você postou, deve ser criado em um novo arquivo?

Comment: Dois arquivos, um `PercentTextWatcher.java` e um `ActivityForm.java`. Ambos na mesma pasta onde você já tem o `ActivityForm.java`. Se você não conseguir fazer isso, me avise que dou um jeito de colocar no mesmo arquivo facilmente.

Comment: Seria pedir muito que fizesse isso? tentei criar o arquivo aqui e me retornou isso:
Unable to parse template "Class"
Error message: This template did not produce a Java class or an interface

Comment: Ok, editei a resposta.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80737/discussion-between-arthur-santos-and-victor-stafusa).

Answer (score 1):

Analisando o [código do MaskFormatter no GitHub](https://github.com/rtoshiro/MaskFormatter), acho que a abordagem mais fácil é implementar o `TextWatcher` diretamente. O `MaskFormatter` não parece ter sido feito para um caso como o que você tem.

Vou usar uma abordagem baseada em expressão regular. A ideia é que ele valide a entrada de acordo com uma expressão regular. Se a entrada não for válida, descarta o último caractere e tenta de nova até que a string resultante seja válida ou até que torne-se vazia. É isso que o método `format(String)` abaixo faz.

O substituto acho que seria isso:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ActivityForm extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_form);
        EditText percentual = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.percentual_Id);
        PercentTextWatcher mask = new PercentTextWatcher(percentual);
        percentual.addTextChangedListener(mask);
    }

    private static class PercentTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private static final Pattern PERC_PAT =
                Pattern.compile("(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)%?");

        private final TextView textView;

        private String currentText;

        public PercentTextWatcher(TextView textView) {
            this.regex = regex;
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (!charSequence.toString().equals(currentText)) {
                currentText = formatter.format(charSequence.toString());
                textView.setText(currentText);
                if (textView instanceof EditText) {
                    EditText editText = (EditText) textView;
                    editText.setSelection(currentText.length());
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        }

        private static String format(String in) {
            if (in == null) return "";
            for (String s = in; !s.isEmpty(); s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1)) {
                if (PERC_PAT.matcher(s).matches()) return s;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

[**Veja aqui um teste do método `format(String)` do código acima.**](https://ideone.com/EDbr7m)

Observe que há duas classes nesse arquivo. A classe `PercentTextWatcher` é usada para substituir a `MaskTextWatcher`.

Se preferir utilizar 0% a 100% ao invés de 1% a 100%, basta trocar a expressão regular para `"(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)%?"` ao invés de `"(?:[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100)%?"`.